# echo array before and after values have been added

Tags: php, arrays

How do I modify my code that it echo's the array before and after a value has been inserted?

For example

`original colors Red Green Blue Yellow Orange`

`with added colors Red Green Blue Yellow Orange Violet Magenta`

Herewith the code I have so far:

```
$arr = array("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Orange");

$arr[] = 'Violet';
$arr[] = 'Magenta';

foreach($arr as $printArray){
    echo $printArray . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: as in print_r($arr);?

Comment: @Faye you can do it like this while definition do this `$arr =$arrayCopy= array("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Orange");` after that you can compare the difference as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be simpler:

```
$arr = array("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Orange");

//echo originals
echo "original colors " . implode(" ", $arr) . "<br>";

//add some
$arr[] = 'Violet';
$arr[] = 'Magenta';

//echo new ones
echo "with added colors " . implode(" ", $arr) . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could track how many elements you have in the original array and then simply use that index to add something to the output.

```
$arr = array( "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Orange" );

$originalCount = count( $arr );

$arr[] = 'Violet';
$arr[] = 'Magenta';

foreach( $arr as $index => $printArray )
{
    if( $index == $originalCount )
        echo "With Added Colors:<br>";

    echo $printArray . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, While `definition` of that array, `maintain a copy of the array`. Optionally you can store `$arrayCopy` variable somewhere in you `DB` as an array.

```
<?php
$arr = $arrayCopy=array("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Orange");

$arr[] = 'Violet';
$arr[] = 'Magenta';

echo implode(",", $arrayCopy);//original array
echo PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo "with added colors: ".implode(",", $arr);//array with new data
```

Comment: Thank you so much @SahilGulati